# Submit button inside form tag doesn't work with function (using AJAX)

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to retrieve data from server using AJAX, JSON, JSP. This is my html code looks like...

```
    <form action="controller">
        <input type="text" name="num">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="selectAll">
        <button type="submit" onclick="showCustomer()">Click button.</button>
    </form>

    <div id="view"></div>
    <script>
        function showCustomer() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("POST", "controller", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

The problem is submit button's oclick function doesn't work. I've already searched and followed what other answers here suggested but doesn't work either...

If I give a specific parameters to url, it works perfectly. What's my problem and what should I do?

```
    <button type="button" onclick="showCustomer()">click button</button>
    <div id="dataView"></div>
    <script>
        function showCustomer() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("dataView").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("POST", "controller?command=selectAll&num=200", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest) post it will help you to solve above problem .